# Finding a records twice and removing from a database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to search a database where Column A says if a record is Added, or removed.

If the search finds and account number which shows a record showing Added, and another record with the same account number as Removed then it will delete the Added Record.

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what I have so far: SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE F1 <> '' AND (FIELD6="Added" OR "REMOVED");

Comment: Don't write code in comments, edit your question and add the code with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be:

```
Delete * From YourTable
Where Field6 = "Added" And AccountNummber In
    (Select AccountNumber From YourTable As T
    Where T.AccountNumber = YourTable.AccountNumber
    And T.Field6 = "Removed")
```